# Get random row for each GROUP of GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT *
 FROM table1 
 JOIN table2 
    ON table1.appId = table2.appId 
 WHERE table1.appId IS NOT NULL 
 ORDER 
    BY table2.count DESC
     , table1.appId
     , RAND()
```

that produces:

| id | appId | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 |
| 8 | 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 5 | 2 |
| 7 | 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 2 |

I only need one random row for each appId, but I can't solve it using a simple `GROUP BY appId` given that it returns always the same result.

My results should look like this:

| id | appId | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 |
| 7 | 5 | 2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to select all the ids of each appId by random order in a comma separated list and then with `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` pick the first one:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY RAND()), ',', 1) id,
       appId, count
FROM .........
WHERE ...........
GROUP BY appId, count
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: it appears from the question that they just want to group by appId; if so, a self-join will be needed to get the count for the selected id

Comment: this doesn't seem to work if there are more attributes (see the updated question)

Comment: @guidev this works for the question as you posted it. If you have a new requirement you can post a new question.